# Vue.js element not updating when changed in a callback function

Tags: javascript, dom, vue.js

I have a file `app.js` with the following vue object:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    test: ''
  }
});
```

I also have a separate js file which is loaded after the `app.js` file.

When the js file contains the following code, the object will update and show on the page.

```
app.test = 'test'
$(document).ready(function() {

}
```

However if I move the first line into the document ready callback function then the element doesn't update on the page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  app.test = 'test'
}
```

I am not quite sure why this is happening... Would someone be able to explain this to me? And potentially let me know of a way so that I can update the element in the document ready callback function.

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this to begin with?

Comment: I'm actually trying to update the value in a websocket event callback function. This just emulated the behavior in a simpler and shorter way.

Comment: Instead of `document.ready`, could you use the `mounted` event in Vue?

Answer (score 1):

In an isolated example the problem you've described doesn't occur. The problem must be somewhere in the code you've omitted from your question.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    test: 'foo'
  }
});

$(() => {
 app.test = 'bar';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{ test }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I apologize for wasting your time. I should have looked further into it before posting.

Comment: @Pabi It's no problem, hope you find out where your issue lies.

Comment: Turns out the problem arises when I have two instances of the vue object loaded at the same time.